# Stuck in "Ubuntu: clean“ mode after battery died

Tags: boot, dell, battery

My Dell XPS 13 went out of battery this morning. Nothing unusual.

But when restarting it, it was doing a "clean up“ of some sort.

After it got stuck with this I pushed the restart button and it immediately shut down and I started it again.

But now it just shows

```
UBUNTU: recovering journal
UBUNTU: clean, 861729/3130948 files, 24559866/124156928 blocks
```

The Dell Pro Support was not really helpful, telling me he knew more about Windows than about  Ubuntu (even though I bought the laptop with Ubuntu pre-installed ...) and that I should maybe reinstall/repair the Grub. Or use a recovery image of Dells Ubuntu to wipe the system and reinstall it.

I really need the data on my machine and would appreciate any help very much.

I found a similar question here where they suggested to reinstall the nvidia drivers, but I don‘t have a graphics card in my laptop.

[image]

Comment: I solved the issue by reinstalling ubuntu.

Comment: It sounds a bit extreme to me, next time maybe use ctrl+alt+f3 to use the terminal and maybe figure out what is wrong